# WCF + Website. File is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, web

I'm getting this error:
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020) (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config line 111)

The problem is that this works locally, but when I publish it at www.medicallperu.com/services/Medicall.svc/Login it gives me that error. I've no way to restart the server or anything, I just know that it works on my local server.

I'm running a WCF on the same domain that a website, I saw somewhere that this might cause an issue, like the one I'm experimenting.

Comment: asp-classic?  Don't you mean ASP.NET?  They are **not** the same thing...

Comment: Yes, sorry it is ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a Virtual Dir for my WCF instead of just having it on a subfolder of my web application.

Answer (score 0):

Error

```
Error   12  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\CloudKase.exe" to "bin\Debug\Some.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Some.exe' because it is being used by another process.
```

I have solution for this error that go to the task manager and find some.exe to makes end task closed that first after that you can run the project without any bug.

Happy Coding :)